# Load Remote Image and add to Scroll View

Tags: scrollview, coronasdk

I'm loading an image from a URL and I'm trying to get it to appear on my scroll view, but it seems to only print it on the main view. Is there a way I can tell it to print on the scroll view?

This is the code I'm using:

```
rowImg = display.loadRemoteImage("http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg", "GET", networkListener, "banner.png",system.TemporaryDirectory,  (globalData.contentX * rows2) + globalData.contentX/2, 20 + (i - 1) % 6 * 140)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

local scrollView = widget.newScrollView{
    width = display.contentWidth,
    height = display.contentHeight,
    scrollWidth = 0,
    scrollHeight = 0,
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    hideBackground = true
}
localGroup:insert(scrollView)


local function networkListener( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
                print ( "Network error - download failed" )
        else
                event.target.alpha = 0
                transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
                scrollView:insert(event.target)  -- This will add your remote image to the scroll view
        end
end
display.loadRemoteImage( "http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg", "GET", networkListener, "helloCopy.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 0, 0 )
```

Keep Coding............ :)